# "Reverse" input in Python

Tags: python, input, python-2.7, user-input

#### What I want isn't a full reversal of letters but just the order of inputted data.

#### For example:

```
raw_input('Please type in your full name')

... John Smith
```

How do I output this as Smith John?

Comment: Tiny note: you tagged as `python-3.x` but you used `raw_input`...did you mean to use `input`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply split the string into a list (here I use `' '` as the split character), reverse it, and put it back together again:

```
s = raw_input('Please type in your full name')
' '.join(reversed(s.split(' ')))
```

Comment: @nneonneo.. do we need that `' '` for splitting.. I am getting the same output with `split()`

Comment: This is more explicit. `split()` splits by all whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
name = raw_input('Please type in your full name')
name = name.split()
print name[-1] + ',', ' '.join(name[:-1])
```

This is in Python 2, but since you're using `raw_input`, I think that's what you want. This method works if they enter a middle name, so "Bob David Smith" becomes, "Smith, Bob David".

Answer (score 2):

A small variation on @nnenneo's answer, but this is what I would have done:

```
>>> s = raw_input('Please type in your full name: ')
Please type in your full name: foo bar
>>> ' '.join(s.split(' ')[::-1])
'bar foo'
```